# Why does Powershell replace commas with whitespaces?

Tags: string, powershell, split

I'm doing some script in Powershell to automate a task. This script is going to get arguments, such as:

```
PS > myscript.ps1 par=a,1,2,0.1 par=b,3,4,0.1 par=c,5,6,0.1 bin=file.exe exeargs="fixed args for file.exe"
```

In short, `file.exe` is an executable which accept parameters (including a, b and c) and this ps1 script is going to execute `file.exe` passing args `a`, `b` and `c` within the specified range, varying 'em by the specified precision.

The question is, I first split each `$arg in $args` by the character "=", and then I should split them by "," to get the specified values.

The thing is, when I do:

```
foreach ($arg in $args)
{
    $parts = ([string] $arg).split("=")
    Write-Host $parts[1]
}
```

The output is

```
a 1 2 0.1
b 3 4 0.1
c 5 6 0.1
file.exe
fixed args for file.exe
```

I.e., it already substituted the "," character with a whitespace, so my second split should be with white space, not with comma.

Any guess on why does it happen?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all why are you writing it like a C program or something? You don't have to pass arguments like that, use `$args` and split on `=` etc. when Powershell has a more powerful concept of parameters, whereby you can pass the named paramters and arguments rather than doing the parsing that you are doing. ( More on parameters here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315296.aspx)

With that said, let me answer your question:

What you are doing is when you pass in arguments like:

`par=a,1,2,0.1 par=b,3,4,0.1 par=c,5,6,0.1 bin=file.exe exeargs="fixed args for file.exe"`

you are passing in array of arrays. The first element is the array with elements:

```
par=a
1
2
0.1
```

Ok coming to the split:

When you do `[string] $a`, you are converting the array into a string. By default this means an array with elements `1,2,3` will become `1 2 3`.

So your first argument there `par=a,1,2,0.1`, becomes `par=a 1 2 0.1` and the split on `=` means `parts[1]` becomes `a 1 2 0.1`, which is what you see.

So how can you retain the comma?

Just make an array to be converted into a string with `,` inbetween than space, right?

Here are some ways to do that:

Using `-join` operator:

```
foreach ($arg in $args)
{

    $parts = ($arg -join ",").split("=")
    Write-Host $parts[1]
}
```

now you will see the output with the commas that you want.

Another way, using `$ofs` special variable:

```
foreach ($arg in $args)
{
    $ofs =","
    $parts = ([string] $arg).split("=")
    Write-Host $parts[1]
}
```

(more on $ofs here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/07/15/what-is-ofs.aspx )

Disclaimer - All this explanation to  make you understand what is happening. Please do not continue this and use paramters.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening in the parsing of the command line for your script and not during the split() method.  To see this, try putting a "Write-Host $args" at the beginning, like so:

```
Write-Host $args
foreach ($arg in $args)
{
    $parts = ([string] $arg).split("=")
    Write-Host $parts[1]
}
```

This is because the ',' character is used to separate elements in an array.  For example:

```
PS C:\temp> $a = 1,2,3
PS C:\temp> Write-Host $a
1 2 3
PS C:\temp> $a.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

Try this command line instead:

```
.\myscript.ps1 "par=a,1,2,0.1" "par=b,3,4,0.1" "par=c,5,6,0.1" "bin=file.exe" "exeargs=fixed args for file.exe"
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried something similar: putting like `par="a,1,2,0.1"` and so on. But that is boring, to put " around every parameter. Do you know any reason why does powershell do that? ty

Comment: Edited - Basically the ',' character makes it parse as an array rather than just a string